# What’s wrong with my truck

Tags: engine, chevrolet, silverado

Hi all I have a 08 Silverado 5.3 it has been a great truck but recently been giving me problems. I have a tester and it says I have codes p0036 p0054 p0140 p0141 p0300 p0455 I just recently changed the spark plugs and even before I changed the plugs it was shooting these codes any idea would be greatly appreciated. Also the stabilitrak off service traction control message shows on my dash.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the plugs was probably irrelevant.

P0036 p0054 p0140 and p0141 all relate to oxygen sensor 2. Either the wiring connections are bad, or it has failed.

p0300 is "random misfiring" which isn't very informative on its own, but p0455 is "large leak in the EVAP emission system" - which could well be causing the random misfiring if you have an air leak into the fuel system somewhere.

New spark plugs won't do any harm, but they won't fix those two sets of problems.

Comment: "We have a EVAP leak down here - large leak, very dangerous."